# How to enable C-U/C-D with ReSharper installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, vsvim

I have recently installed VsVim and ReSharper into VS 2010. The ReSharper hotkeys seem to override those of VsVim.

Is there a way to make VsVim commands higher priority than those of ReSharper?

More specifically, I would like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to work like in Vim.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> the shortcut conflict window appears and there doesn't seem to be a <kbd>PgDown</kbd> option.

[image: ReSharper shortcut conflict window]

Comment: Did you try modifying ReSharper shortcuts in Tools -> Customize -> Keyboard ?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't able to associate Ctrl+D to PgDown.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell ReSharper that you want Visual Studio to handle those keyboard shortcuts instead of ReSharper (in the window you show in your question), and tell VsVim that you want it to handle them instead of Visual Studio.

In up-to-date versions of VsVim, you do this by going to `Tools -> Options -> VsVim -> Keyboard` (by "Tools" I mean the menu in the Visual Studio menu bar). There you can configure what you want VsVim to handle. There used to be an "Options" button at the end of Vim's status bar, as [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14421214/834176) says, but that is no longer true.

[image: Options window]

I have <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> set up to scroll in my VsVim configuration so I can vouch for it working.

Answer (score 1):

On the window in the image select Visual Studio.  Then open a text file (.cs, .cshtml, whatever) and in the bottom right of the window is an "options" button to the far right of the vsVim cmd line you type into.  Click the options button and you will get a list.  It will say "Ctrl_D handle with" and your options will be Visual Studio or vsVim; just switch it.  You can come back and undo it later.  I have VS2010, Resharper and vsVim and don't have the issue, but it may also be a .vimrc config setting where you need to disable the msvim options.